# NamedPipe goes missing when connecting multiple times

Tags: c#, .net, named-pipes

I have 2 applications that talk to each other over a named pipe (using H.Pipes). Before I open the pipe to send data, I do a check if the pipe exists with:

```
var pipes = Directory.GetFiles(@"\\.\pipe\").ToList();
if (!pipes.Contains($@"\\.\pipe\{pipename}"))
{
   throw new FileNotFoundException($"NamedPipe ({pipename}) does not exist");
}
```

The client application can connect to the pipe just fine as long as I do it serially. When I try to bombard the pipe with multiple parallel calls it starts throwing exceptions that it can't find the pipe.

The server simply is a windows service that starts a pipeserver and waits forever for clients to connect.

The client app is a console application that accepts a single arg, and sends that arg over the pipe and waits for it to be processed.

I use Powershell to do 50 parallel calls to stress the system. This then starts throwing exceptions it can't find the pipe, but sometimes it gives me a proper response.

Is there anyone with experience with named pipes who can explain to me what is happening.

Comment: You need to get the OS stable again, start with the installed anti-malware product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved this by using Polly to catch the FileNotFoundException and retrying several times. The pipe is there but it doesn't always show up. Simply retrying was enough.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).